# Can a SAFE be deployed using a paymaster / gasless transaction?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

One big selling point of account abstraction is transparent set up of smart wallets for users.

Given this, I'm not super clear from the documentation if gasless SAFE deployment is supported?

- https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/protocol-kit#deploysafe

Is it possible to use e.g. [Gelato](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/relay) to cover the gas fee when onboarding a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use gelato to deploy safe. Just add the `SafeProxyFactory` Contract on the dashboard of gelato to make it gasless and you will be able to deploy safe without paying any gas fees.